# Get records from two date columns in db in laravel via eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

i have a leaves table called `user_leaves` in which leaves taken by users are stored, table has this structure.

```
id, leave_type_id, from_date, to_date, status, created_at, updated_at.
```

`leave_type_id` is basically a foreign key of types of leaves my system has.

I want to fetch all leaves taken by a user in a range of two dates like `start_date` and `end_date` (for example all leaves from `2020-08-01` to `2020-08-31` .

I want records in numbers like,

```
 {
   "user_id" : 1,
   "leaves" : 
    {
    "medical_leave" : 2,
    "earned_leave" : 5,
    "sick_leave" : 3
    }
  }
```

I used the code

```
                   $UserLeaves = UserLeave::whereDate('date_from', '>=', $start_date)
                            ->whereDate('date_from', '<=', $end_date)
                            ->get();
```

The problem is that if i choose `from_date` to query my result ,and then loop through `$UserLeaves` to get all days between from_date and to_date for each leave_type.
Their are cases when `to_date` may exceed my end_date and thus giving wrong data if i calculate all days between from_date and to_date.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this

```
$baseQuery = $baseQuery->where(function ($query) use ($date_created_from, $date_created_to) {
    if (isset($date_created_from) && $date_created_from != '') {
        $dateFrom = Carbon::parse($date_created_from)->format('Y-m-d');
        $query->whereDate('date_column', '>=', $dateFrom);
    }

    if (isset($date_created_to) && $date_created_to != '') {
        $dateEnd = Carbon::parse($date_created_to)->format('Y-m-d');
        $query->whereDate('date_column', '<=', $dateEnd); 
    } 
});
```

Where

1. `$baseQuery` is the query you write to perform all your selections, aggregation etc.

The above code accounts for null values and additionally you could perform additional checks before appending the query to your base query like "date from is not greater than 1 week before today".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `whereBetween` clause and in wherebetween you can pass `$from_date` and `$to_date` as below:

```
$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-05-02');

youModal::whereBetween('column_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```